# MySQL 4 Tables Join and Group by as main table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables. I would like to know if it is possible to get min hotel price with any join. There is an example data.

```
Table: hotels

            id   name               country         city        phone
```

---

```
            1   P Hotel              France         Paris       055555555
            2   C Hotel              Portuqal       Lisbon      545489485
            3   D Hotel              ........       ......      ........
            4   E Hotel              ........       ......      ........
            .
            .
            .
```

Table: room_types

```
            id           name     
----------------------------------------------  
            1              Standart Room       
            2              Deluxe Room         
            3              B-Plus               
            4              Villa
```

Table: hotel_rooms

```
            id          hotel_id    room_id
----------------------------------------------  
            1              1          1
            2              1          3
            3              1          4
            4              2          4
            5              2          2
            6              3          1
            7              3          2
            8              4          1
```

Table: prices

```
            id          price_pp        price_tp    discount    hotel_rooms_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1              123.00       323.00         15           1
            2              212.34       112.00         24           2
            3              12.50        62.00          29           3
            4              523.00       323.00         15           4
            5              412.34       112.00         24           5
            6              62.50        62.00          29           6
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

Which room type doesnt matter i just need min price for hotel. I would like to get result like this :

Table: prices

```
        id   name               country         city        phone       price_pp        price_tp    discount    
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1   P Hotel              France         Paris       055555555     12.50          62.00         29
        2   C Hotel              Portuqal       Lisbon      545489485     412.34         112.00        24       
        3   D Hotel              ........       ......      ........
        4   E Hotel
```

**Update.**
That is what i tried, but results just show hotels and MIN(prices.price_pp) i also want to get other columns from prices.

```
 SELECT hotels.*, MIN(prices.price_pp)
    FROM hotels
        LEFT JOIN hotel_rooms
            ON hotels.id = hotel_rooms.hotel_id    
        LEFT JOIN prices
            ON hotel_rooms.id = prices.hotel_rooms_id
    GROUP BY hotels.id
```

Comment: This smells like homework.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried till now?

Comment: You haven't told us how to compute the price for any given room. Your `prices` table contains two columns showing price, as well as a discount.  How should those columns be interpreted to come up with the lowest price for each row -- each room?

Comment: You wrote " i also want to get other rows from prices" . I suppose you mean "I want to get the other *columns* from the `prices` table."

Comment: @O.Jones I'm sorry, yes other columns from the prices table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for a result set showing one row per hotel, with details of the hotel and the cheapest room in the hotel. But that is my guess.

I also am forced to guess how your relationships work. Does `prices.hotel_rooms_id` relate to `hotel_rooms.id`?

**Pro tip:** The more time you spend specifying your problems, the less time you will spend trying to solve them.

Two steps here:

1. find the `hotel_id` and `price_pp` values of the cheapest room in each hotel.
2. use `JOIN`s to retrieve the hotel and room details.

Find the lowest price `MIN(price_pp)` in each hotel.

```
                 SELECT MIN(p.price_pp) price, r.hotel_id
                   FROM prices p
                   JOIN hotel_rooms r ON p.hotel_rooms_id = r.id
                  GROUP BY r.hotel_id
```

Run that query on its own. Convince yourself it works.

Then you can use that as a subquery to retrieve your details.

```
 SELECT hotels.*, prices.*
   FROM hotels
   JOIN hotel_rooms ON hotels.id = hotel_rooms.hotel_id
   JOIN prices ON hotel_rooms.id = prices.hotel_rooms_id
   JOIN (
                     SELECT MIN(p.price_pp) price, r.hotel_id
                       FROM prices p
                       JOIN hotel_rooms r ON p.hotel_rooms_id = r.id
                      GROUP BY r.hotel_id
        ) x  ON prices.price_pp = x.price 
            AND hotel_rooms.hotel_id = x.hotel_id
```

This is an example of a classic query pattern: Find the details of a rows in a table containing extreme values (minimum, maximum, etc).   The `ON` clause in the last two lines does the work of extracting the interesting detail rows.

Comment: I might have left some mistakes in this. **Do not** just copy my answer and use it. Be sure you understand it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that save my life. Now I know what should i do next time thanks for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 2more columns to your select list. Something like this -

```
SELECT hotels.*, MIN(prices.price_pp), MIN(prices.price_tp), MIN(prices.discount)
FROM hotels
    LEFT JOIN hotel_rooms
        ON hotels.id = hotel_rooms.hotel_id    
    LEFT JOIN prices
        ON hotel_rooms.id = prices.hotel_rooms_id
GROUP BY hotels.id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This query can retrieve values of `price_pp`, `price_tp`, and `discount` from different rows of the `prices` table for each hotel. That's not quite right.